# Collection View reloadData method shows a cell as selected

Tags: ios

I currently have a collectionView that has cells that a user would select (can be multiple), and upon tapping a record button the values of these selected cells are recorded. In addition to recording, i also want to clear the selections from the collectionView so the process can be repeated. I currently have collectionView.reloadData() in the record button but It doesn't clear the selections of the user, instead a cell is shown as selected without executing the selection (selection will determine actions on screen). This selected cell always changes; it jumps around but always in the same order. Does anybody know why this occurs? Also, is reloadData() the correct/efficient way to clear the selections of a collectionView?

Here is where i register the CustomCell Nib

```
viewDidLoad()
{

    let nib3 = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.registerNib(nib3, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}
```

Here are the Delegate methods and DataSource methods i implement

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return outcomeList.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let title:String = outcomeList[indexPath.row]
        let cell:CustomCell = self. collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.label.text = title
        cell.tag = indexPath.row + 19
        cell.selected = false
        return cell

}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        let cell: CustomCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        cell.label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


        cellSelected(cell)

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell:CustomCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

This is the method i call when the cell is selected

```
func cellSelected(sender: CustomCell)
{
    let text:String = fieldedResultLabel.text!
    resultLabel.text = text + sender.label.text! + "-"            
}
```

Here is the record IBAction

```
@IBAction func recordButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    // cdao is a custom object that handles all my CoreData requests
    cdao.storeResult(resultlabel)
    // reset the collection View so that all cells show as not selected i do this by reloadData() but still shows some cells as selected
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UICollectionView`, much like `UITableView`, allow for cell reuse. When you reload the view, that previously selected cell is being reused, and most likely not for the same location (hence the "jumping around" you see). When you receive a `UICollectionViewDelegate` call to `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, within the body of your implementation, be sure to deselect the cell.

e.g.

**Objective-C**:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // do the rest of your processing of the selected item
}
```

**Swift**:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    // do the rest of your processing of the selected item
}
```

This is preferable, since it provides animated feedback to the user, versus it showing itself being selected, then suddenly being redrawn via the `reloadData`. You can probably, at this point, eliminate reloading the table after every selection since you are now handling deselection properly, and not brute force by a table reload.

**Update**

I created a little sample app that might mimic what you are doing as I understand it based on your description. The code is small, and works as I described without having to reload the collection view after processing the selected cells. Obviously, I have set up the views and controls in a Storyboard, but the gist of it should be obvious:

```
class CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    override var selected : Bool {
        didSet {
            self.layer.backgroundColor = (self.selected) ? UIColor.redColor().CGColor : UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView : UICollectionView?;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
            collectionView.registerClass(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Custom View")
            collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 16;
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Custom View", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.selected = false
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true) can be called here...
        // but if you are wanting the cells to retain selection visually,
        // then wait until you batch process them below
    }

    @IBAction func handleButtonPress(sender : AnyObject ) {
        // do your updates to your backing store, etc.

        // manually deselect the cells for a pleasant user visual experience, or alternatively...
        // invoke self.collectionView.reloadData() to bulk reload instead
        if let selectedCells = self.collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems() as? [NSIndexPath] {
            for indexPath in selectedCells {
                self.collectionView?.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Thank you for the full implementation. The problem is that you change the background and text color of the cell(s) explicitly when they are selected from within the delegate callback `didSelectCellAtIndexPath`. Since your delegate's `didDeslectCellAtIndexPath` never gets called (calling `collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)` does not invoke it) unless manually tapped, your cell's background and text colors do not get reset, and remain the "selected" colors through the reuse cycle. Go back and look carefully at my sample again, it pretty much demonstrates a possible workable solution for your problem. Handling the selected state change in the custom cell will ensure it gets update correctly when the selected state alters.

`reloadData` is fine for bulk resetting your collection view, unless the backing data is expensive to obtain, in which case you are probably better off getting the list of selected cells and deselecting them explicitly (which my code demonstrates as well). Deselecting explicitly will animate the deselection, which is visually more appealing than a bulk reload.

Comment: i tried your suggestions but i still get the same result. Ill add some source code

Comment: are you relying on the selected states of the collection view items when you invoke `grabSelectedCellsValues()` to determine which ones to grab? If that is the case, then you'll want to call the same `deselectItemAtIndexPath(...)` for each one you determine is selected. You might want to post the body of `grabSelectedCellsValues()`` method as well.

Comment: How is your cell class registered and dequeued? I think you will need to share more code to expose the flaw.

Comment: See my update...your implementation of indicating selected state via background and text color changes aren't truly coordinated to the selected state of the cell. Align those, and everything will fall into place.

Comment: Works just like i had hoped. Thanks for taking the time to help me out!